# Looping inside the array_values function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I want to loop through the values of array which contain $i variable in it,

My code for array looks like this,

```
foreach($fields_names as $k => $v) {
      $handle_data[] ='$rowdata[$i][$fields_names[\''.$v.'\']]';
}

for($i=0;$i<$number_rows_excel;$i++){

$sql.= "('".implode("','", array_values($handle_data))."'),". "<br/>";

        }
```

When I am echoing $sql, I am getting like this ,

```
INSERT INTO eximport (`S.No`, `Patent#`, `Title`) VALUES ('$rowdata[$i][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[$i][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$rowdata[$i][$fields_names['Title']]')
```

It should have to display like this

```
INSERT INTO eximport (`S.No`, `Patent#`, `Title`) VALUES ('$rowdata[0][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[0][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$rowdata[0][$fields_names['Title']]')
```

How can I use the variable $i to loop through array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used this code which helps me to insert the row, appending ',' for each values for insert

```
 foreach($val_ary as $new_data_string){
    $newArray[] = implode("','",$new_data_string);
        }

//Inserting data into the table     
        for($tr=0;$tr< $data->sheets[0]['numRows']-2;$tr++)
        {
         $sql ="INSERT INTO eximport($fieldnames)values('$newArray[$tr]')";
         mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());  
         //$p1 = $db->insert_id;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$i=0;
foreach($fields_names as $k => $v) {
    $handle_data[] ='$rowdata['.$i.'][$fields_names[\''.$v.'\']]'; $i++;
}
```

Comment: first thanks for the reply , it is diaplaying like this     ('$rowdata[0][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[1][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$rowdata[2][$fields_names['Title']]'),
('$rowdata[0][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[1][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$rowdata[2][$fields_names['Title']]'), instead i want like this ('$rowdata[0][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[0][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$rowdata[0][$fields_names['Title']]'),
('$rowdata[1][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[1][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$rowdata[1][$fields_names['Title']]'),

Comment: Can you please explain what is your expected result.Because the problem is in the loop of `$fields_names` only

Comment: your code is running like this'$rowdata[0][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[1][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$‌​rowdata[2][$fields_names['Title']]'), all i want is like '$rowdata[0][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[0][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$‌​rowdata[0][$fields_names['Title']]'), and after that increment the array values to '$rowdata[1][$fields_names['S.No']]','$rowdata[1][$fields_names['Patent#']]','$‌​rowdata[1][$fields_names['Title']]')

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to have the `$rowdata[]` parts written in the query, but the actual value of that array-entry?

So, you should simple nest your loops, like so. Remember, you are looping every Field, which means, you dont need to do any implode on the data. I assume that your data Sets are inside the Array `$data` and $field_names is just a List of fieldnames.:

```
$data = array(
   array("name" => "DataSet1", "value" => 56),
   array("name" => "DataSet2", "value" => 5)
);

$field_names = array("name","value");

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (";
$sql .= implode($fields_names,",");
$sql .= ")VALUES";

for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
   $sql .= "(";
   foreach($fields_names as $k => $v) {
      $sql.= "'".$data[$i][$v]."',";

   }
   //remove trailing ","
   $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
   $sql .= "),";
}
//remove trailing ","
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
```

This will generate:

`INSERT INTO table (name,value)VALUES('DataSet1','56'),('DataSet2','5')`

Comment: ia m getting field names from this code                        foreach($fields_names as $k => $v) {
  $handle_data[] ='$rowdata['.$i.'][$fields_names[\''.$v.'\']]'; 
}
and data from this                           for($i=0;$i<$number_of_fields;$i++)
{ 
$fields_names[] =mysql_field_name($res, $i); 
}
 actually $rowdata['this_is_row_number']['this_will_get_name_of_field'] , how can i combine the field name with its associative data

Comment: I don't get why you are adding `'$rowdata['.$i.'][$fields_names[\''.$v.'\']]` to the handle array. This is a string and will not be resolved into anything of value. Please provide a example dataset of your arrays, containing example values. Then we can help you.

Comment: i have used this code which helps me to insert the row,                          ppeding ',' for each values for insert
  foreach($val_ary as $new_data_string){
        $newArray[] = implode("','",$new_data_string);
   }
 
 //Inserting data into the table  
   for($tr=0;$tr< $data->sheets[0]['numRows']-2;$tr++)
   {
    $sql ="INSERT INTO eximport($fieldnames)values('$newArray[$tr]')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());  
    //$p1 = $db->insert_id;
    }